# Want to get updated version of DLLs from the specific folders in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get all the latest version of the dlls from the specified location of the folder, but my script outputs nothing. Can some one tell me how to solve this?

```
$path = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector ODBC 8.0" 
$files = Get-ChildItem $path  -include *.dll 

 $files |
    ForEach-Object {
        try {
            $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty FileVersion ($_.VersionInfo.FileVersion)
            $_ | Add-Member NoteProperty AssemblyVersion (
                [Reflection.AssemblyName]::GetAssemblyName($_.FullName).Version
            )
        } catch {}
        $_
    } |
    Select-Object Name,FileVersion,AssemblyVersion`
```

Comment: Change `$path = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector ODBC 8.0"` **-->** `$path = "C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector ODBC 8.0\*"` **or** change `$files = Get-ChildItem $path  -include *.dll ` **-->** `$files = Get-ChildItem $path  -recurse -include *.dll`

Comment: I'd go with `$files = Get-ChildItem $path -recurse -include *.dll` as documentation explains `-Recurse` as adding `\*` to the path is a less obvious.